# Probability equals to fraction with arbitrary constant

Tags: probability

Let $A,B,C$ be three independent events that satisfy $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=p$.

I am trying to prove the following statement:

$P(A|A^C∪B^C∪C^C) = \frac{p(1+p)}{p^2+p+1}$

Well, I can write that:

$P(A|A^C∪B^C∪C^C)=\frac{P(A∩(A^C∪B^C∪C^C))}{P(A^C∪B^C∪C^C)}$

And try to simplify the denominator to: $-3p^2+3p+P(A^C∩B^C∩C^C)$

Now I am confused with the simplifying of $P(A^C∩B^C∩C^C)$. I know that $A,B,C$ are independent, but not sure whether I can simplify it to $(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)$.

Perhaps I miss something.

Comment: You can. If $A,B,C$ are independent, then so are their complements.

Comment: Thanks. From here I think to proceed to the numerator. May I state that $P(A∩(A^C∪B^C∪C^C))=P(A)P(A^C∪B^C∪C^C)$? Or there is a need to prove their independence?

Comment: For the numerator, use the law of total probablity.

Comment: On the other hand, there’s no reason that $A$ and $A^C \cup B^C \cup C^C$ are independent. Try using a Venn diagram to find that the numerator is $P(A) -P(A\cap B\cap C)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rightly said, $\displaystyle \small P(A|A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c)=\frac{P(A \cap (A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c))}{P(A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c)}$

Denominator $\small P(A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c)$ $ \small = P(A^c) + P(B^c) + P(C^c) - P(A^c \cap B^c) - P(B^c \cap C^c) - P(A^c \cap C^c) + P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c)$

Similarly,

Numerator $\small P(A \cap (A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c)) = P(A) \ P (B^c \cup C^c)$

Now for example, $\small P(A^c \cap B^c) = (1-p)^2, P(A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c) = (1-p)^3$

Answer (score 0):

For the denominator, use the De [Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)
$$P(A^C\cup B^C \cup C^C) =P((A\cap B\cap C)^C)= 1 - P(A\cap B\cap C) = 1-p^3 = (1-p)(1+p+p^2)$$

For the numerator, simlarly
$$P(A)P(B^C\cup C^C) = P(A)P((B\cap C)^C) = P(A)(1-P(B\cap C))$$